# Using OpenLayers/jQuery without CDN

Tags: openlayers-2, css, localhost

I was wondering what are the necessary files for hosting a webgis server with OpenLayers3 without using a CDN?

I am testing on a `localhost` without internet access. It  doesn't work to merely copy the direct `js` (and `css`) file pointed to by a CDN such as

```
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol.js
```

to the local webserver as `<script src="js/ol.js"></script>`.

Also, the same question holds for jquery and bootstrap. I had

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But I wasn't sure how to get a complete local version for those.

Comment: You can run your own server using nodejs locally, if you first pull all the source files from github. You will not need an internet connection for this. If you are interested in this approach, I will write it up.

Comment: @JohnBarça Yes, I am interested in that approach. I've asked a new question about it http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123449/how-to-run-webgis-server-with-openlayers-jquery-locally, in case there are more traditional ways that should be considered right. I did notice openlayers has something named `npm` in it, but I am not familiar with using node.js. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the v3.0.0 distribution from https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases , then copy the js file(s) inside the build/ subdirectory to your webserver.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I was looking at the source tar ball, which didn't have the build subdir.